How can I query attributes with struck array data type?
I have this value with data type array<struct<id:string,name:string,values:array<string>>
[
    {id=gid://test/1234, name=Size, values=[L, M, S, XS]}, 
    {id=gid://test/12345, name=Color, values=[Black]}
]

How can I query to get the size value with output like this
[L, M, S, XS]?
I tried this
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
    mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(options) AS t (option_struct)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(option_struct.values) AS size_value
WHERE 
    option_struct.name = 'Size'


Please add the desired output (and actual one).

If the goal is to get the array you don't need to use second unnest:
-- sample data
with dataset(options) as(
 values (array[
        cast(ROW('gid://test/1234', 'Size', array['L', 'M', 'S', 'XS']) as ROW(id varchar, name varchar, "values" array(varchar))),
        cast(ROW('gid://test/12345', 'Color', array['Black']) as ROW(id varchar, name varchar, "values" array(varchar)))
    ])
)

-- query
SELECT option_struct."values" as size_value
FROM
    dataset
    , UNNEST(options) AS option_struct
WHERE
    option_struct.name = 'Size';


I tried this approach as well and got this error message line 1:22: mismatched input 'values'. Expecting: '*', 

@lexmadness updated snippet, please check it out. values is a reserved keyword in Trino and requires escaping. Also in theory there can be some variability in the unnest syntax depending on the version used (as far as I remember Presto unnested array of rows into a single column, while Trino flattens them into multiple ones)
